# I can't call a predicate recursively in SWI-Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

Hello I am writing some code in SWI-Prolog to resolve crosswords, and for some reason, the predicate "do_something" fails. The predicate `do_something_else(crss(...), +Q, -L).` works fine. The predicate `do_something(crss(...), +L1, -Lout).` is supposed to recursively add elements form L1 and the list L, returned by predicate do_something_else to the "Lout" list, but for some reason it returns false. I should probably mention that L is a list of lists of atoms and L1 is an array of chars. This program is supposed to solve crosswords. `cross` is a structure that contains the sizes of the whole crossword, a list with all the Questions, their coordinates and spaces that are supposed to be left blank, with their coordinates. THe last list in this structure stores all the possible answers. `Q` is JUST the text of the question, without the coordinates, and `L` is the output List.
`space_length(+crss(...), +Q, -Len)` returns te number of spaces that a question has available for the answer.
`questions(crss(...), -LI)` returns a list with all the questions and their starting coordinates.
`questions_text(+LI, -LIT)` returns a list with just the text of the questions.
This section of code is supposed to return all the questions of the crossword with a list of possible answers. Ex of output:

```
('Afirmativ', [['D', 'A'], ['N', 'U']])
('Negativ', [['D', 'A'], ['N', 'U']]).
```

---

```
 do_something_else(crss(_, _, _, []), _, []).
 do_something_else(crss(_, _, PL, [H | T]), Q, [CL | L]) :-space_length(crss(_, _, PL, _), Q, Len), atom_chars(H, CL), length(CL, Ln), Ln == Len, !, do_something_else(crss(_, _, PL, T), Q, L).
 do_something_else(crss(_, _, PL, [H | T]),Q, L) :- space_length(crss(_, _, PL, _), Q, Len), atom_chars(H, CL), length(CL, Ln), Ln =\= Len, do_something_elese(crss(_, _, PL, T), Q, L).

 do_something(crss(_, _, _, []), [], []).
 do_something(crss(_, _, PL, V), [H | T], [(H, L) |List]) :- do_something_else(crss(_, _, PL, V), H, L), X(crss(_, _, PL, V), T, List).

 pos_sol(crss(_, _, _, []), []).
 pos_sol(crss(_, _, PL, V), List) :- questions(crss(_, _, PL, _), LI), questions_text(LI, LIT), do_something(crss(_, _, PL, V), LIT, List).
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] including the query that you're running?

Comment: Please don't edit the question as the solution. Please don't change the title with SOLVED. You should post an answer to your question instead. I've rolled back the edit. Please post a solution.